# cakephp 3 bin/cake Bake sets user model/controller owner to root

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have just tried the new quick start tutorial in the CakePHP docs.

I have noticed that all user files have the owner permissions set to root and therefor are locked when I try to edit in phpStorm.

Even the directory Template/Users is set to root.

All other files are set to my logged in username.

Is this the expected result? I do not see anything about this in the docs. Should I change the owner of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install CakePHP with composer, it sets the directory/file permissions appropriately so that the web server can access the files it needs.
Bake runs as a shell, so when you bake, it creates models, controllers, and views (templates), and whatever else you baked using the permissions of the user you were logged in as when you ran bake.
If you run bake again logged in as a standard user (not root or sudo), PhpStorm should be able to access the files as writable.

Comment: Thanks, I don't recall being logged in as root/sudo when I baked the Users but I must have been.

Comment: I have to use sudo to get composer to work or it fails to download thus setting owner as root which is a pain.